# Need help on RDS connectivity to QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently created a QuickSight enterprise account and tried to connect to a new data source to my AWS RDS Postgresql. However, I am getting the error “sourceErrorCode:GENERIC_SQL_EXCEPTION” and “sourceErrorMessage:Connection attempt timed out.” whenever I tries to validate the connection (note that SSL is enabled, not sure if this is causing the issue).

I followed the guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rds-vpc-access.html and double checked the settings. The inbound rule is based on my AWS Region while the outbound is open to all.

I checked my RDS setting, and there are two VPC security group tagged to it (one being the new VPC security group for QuickSight, the other is the default).

I am at a loss here. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.